# If you fly in the direction closer to a black hole, are you going forward in time?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, observers

As the title suggests, but I'll reiterate.

Since a black hole has an extremely large gravitational pull, wouldn't you be going forward in time relative to Earth the closer you get to the black hole?

Answer (score 2):

You are always going forward in time no matter where you are, even as you move closer to a black hole. What's different is that as you do move closer, time (as observed by an external observer, eg, relative to earth as you said) is slowed down considerably so that by the time they hit the event horizon, a clock held by the in-falling observer will freeze (according to the earth oberver). This may be what you mean.

To be more precise, the black hole warps the *space-time*  around the black hole.

Comment: But aren't we technically orbiting around the supermassive blackhole in the center of our galaxy? Wouldn't my speed towards it and the gravitational pulling speed of the supermassive black hole cause an increasing time dilation?

Comment: Time dilation means time is slowed from the point of view of the observer. In the reference frame of the person near the black hole, time passes at the normal rate.

Comment: "*time (as observed by an external observer, eg, relative to earth as you said) is slowed down considerably so that by the time they hit the event horizon a clock held by the in-falling observer will freeze (according to the earth oberver).*" - When exactly does he "hit the event horizon", "as observed by an external observer"?

Comment: When he physically reaches it. The external observer will see that the in-falling observers clock stops. You just quoted my answer then asked it.